# Regular Expression with Umlauts in Python 2.7.5

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Why doesn't my regular expression work? I need to use python 2.7.5.
This is my expression:

```
pattern = re.compile('\d{4};[a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜß. -]+;.+')
```

I'm reading a csv file. At the start there must be 4 digits until a `;`, and until the 2nd `;` there must be letters from a-Z, umlauts and `.` or a space or `.`, then after the 2nd `;` there can be any character.

Now my problem: In the second "part" it doesn't accept umlauts like `äöü` or `ß`. In the third "part" where I don't specify the umlauts, its no problem when they occur.

I did put `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By encoding to UTF-8, you entered a *multibyte sequence* into a character class:

```
>>> 'ä'
'\xc3\xa4'
```

Anything outside the ASCII character range requires more than one byte to encode.

Your character class will now match either the 0xC3 byte *or* a 0xA4 byte; your class contains more bytes, and it *may* match `'ä'` but it could also match any other UTF-8 byte sequence with the C3 or A4 bytes.

You'd either have to explicitly match each UTF-8 byte pair (a real pain), *or* decode your data to Unicode strings first and use a Unicode regular expression:

```
re.compile(u'\d{4};[a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜß. -]+;.+', flags=re.UNICODE)
```

Do pass in Unicode text when you use that regular expression

Comment: Thanks man, that worked!!! I have been struggeling with this problem for a few days now..

Comment: shouldn't that be `ru'\d{4}...'` (for a raw-unicode string)?

Comment: @thebjorn: it doesn't *have* to be; a raw string literal is just different syntax for the same result. In this case `\d` remains `\d` in the resulting value. There is no `ru` prefix in Python 3, so for polyglot code (code that needs to run on Python 2 and Python) so I tend to not use that prefix.